# How to store references to other objects in C++?

Tags: c++, reference, smart-pointers, move-semantics

This is a more general question that I'm trying to resolve for C++ best practices. Suppose I want to create objects which store references to each other, like a graph. All objects are owned by the same object, like a Graph object to all the Nodes, which is to say the ownership is fixed.

Here's my idea: a class Graph has a `std::vector` of Nodes, each Node has a `std::vector` of Nodes representing its list of connections. I'm wondering how best to implement this in terms of smart pointers? To my understanding, ownership is unique so the Graph vector should be `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> nodes` and I can populate that as needed. But the `connections` vector, how can I get each node to store references to its connections? These would only be read-only references, and maybe it would be better to name all the nodes and only store the names, or to store connections in the Graph. But **is there a good way of storing references to the connection nodes** as if they were const pointers?

*Note*: this is really about ownership and smart pointers, not about data structures, the graph example is just an example.

Comment: Funny, a graph was the motivating discussion around Herb Sutter's [gcpp](https://github.com/hsutter/gcpp) project with `deferred_ptr`s. That said: this is a bit of a broad and possibly opinion-based question since it can be solved a number of ways; raw pointer-viewing on the nodes with strong `unique_ptr` in the graph, or `weak_ptr`'s in the node and `shared_ptr`s in the `Graph`, or something more exotic like `deferred_ptr`s. Nothing is inherently "right" or "wrong" -- it depends on the use-case and desired quality attributes

Comment: @Human-Compiler I see your point about it being opinion-based, so maybe I can change the question to ask about a particular method and answers could criticize and provide alternatives?

Comment: You already have an answer on the question as-asked -- I would be hesitant to change it in such a way that may invalidate the existing answer (that tends to upset answerers). It's not a bad question at all either way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When discussing "Best Practices", it's important to consider what your quality-attributes and needs are for the code.

There is no "right" or "wrong" answer in the example of code such as a `Graph`; there are varying degrees that solve different problems in different ways -- and it depends strongly on the way its intended to be used.

By-far the simplest way to solve such a problem is for the main container (`Graph`) to have **strong ownership** in the with `unique_ptr`, and to only **view the lifetime** in the internal elements (`Node`) with a raw pointer, e.g.:

```cpp
class Graph
{
    ...
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> m_nodes;
};

class Node
{
    ...
private:
    std::vector<const Node*> m_connected_nodes;
};
```

This would work well, since `Node` cannot mutate its connected nodes, and since `Graph` assumes that `Node` will never outlive it.

**However**, this approach does *not* work if you ever want `Node` to outlive `Graph`, or if you want `Node` to be used across multiple `Graph` objects. If it lives between different `Graph`s, then you may run the risk of a `Node` referring to a dangling pointer -- and this would be bad.

If this is the case, you might need to consider a different ownership pattern, such as `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` ownership:

```cpp
class Graph
{
    ...
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> m_nodes;
};

class Node
{
    ...
private:
    std::vector<std::weak_ptr<const Node*>> m_connected_nodes;
};
```

In this case, `Node`s only weakly know other `Node` objects, whereas `Graph` is the strong owner of them. This prevents the dangling issue, but incurs additional overhead now for the `shared_ptr`'s control node, and for having to check for whether it's alive before accessing `weak_ptr` nodes.

So the correct answer is: **It depends**. If you can get away with the former approach, that's probably the cleanest; you always have 1 owner, and thus the logic is simple and easy to follow.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering how best to implement this in terms of smart pointers?

By not using them. Use a vector of nodes for the graph: `std::vector<Node>`. This is a reasonable default choice until you have a good reason to do otherwise.

> But is there a good way of storing references to the connection nodes as if they were const pointers?

Yes. Const pointers are a good way of storing as if they were const pointers. (And by "const pointer", I presume we are actually talking about pointer to const).

A reference wrapper is another choice. Although it has the advantage of not having representation for null, it does have the downside of clumsy syntax.